# While importing tensorflow error occurred

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

First I installed tensorflow 2.0.0rc1 While importing tensorflow in python 3.6.9 it said import error then I tried tensorflow 1.14.0 but then also error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SUSAMA/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/ten.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\SUSAMA\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please tell how to correct it.

Comment: try `pip install protobuf==3.6.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing **TensorFlow** (TF) CPU prebuilt binaries:

*TensorFlow release binaries version 1.6 and higher are prebuilt with AVX instruction sets.*
See [hardware requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware-requirements) to know more.

Therefore on any CPU that does not have these instruction sets, either CPU or GPU version of TF will fail to load.
Apparently, your CPU model does not support AVX instruction sets. You can still use TensorFlow with the alternatives given below:

- Try Google Colab to use TensorFlow.

  - The easiest way to use TF will be to switch to [google colab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#recent=true). You get pre-installed latest stable TF version. Also you can use `pip install` to install any other preferred TF version.
  - It has an added advantage since you can you easily switch to different hardware accelerators (cpu, gpu, tpu) as per the task.
  - All you need is a good internet connection and you are all set.
- Try to build TF from sources by changing CPU optimization flags.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that my CPU doesnt support AVX instructions, which are used by
Tensorflow > 1.5 causing this import Error. Possible Fixes are afaik:
1.)Tensorflow 1.5:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

2.)Use a prebuilt wheel without AVX intructions (For example for Windows: https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel)

3.)Build Tensorflow from Source for your system.